# I would like to iterate a big Json's properties and sub properties name with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

My final aim is to get all the properties name and its types from a local file path.

```
Example 
{
  "description": "Something",
  "id": "abc.def.xyzjson#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "triggerTime": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Time of adjustment event",
      "source": "ab.cd",
      "pattern": "something",
      "required": true
    },
    "customerId": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Something",
      "source": "ef.gh",
      "required": true
    }, ..... many more properties
```

Under some properties, there are sub-properties and their Type.
I want final Output as-
triggerTime String
customerId String (also sub)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to load the json into `Map<String, Object>` and then to recursively iterate on the map and collect the data you require

Here is the entire solution for you

```
public class JsonProperties
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C://Temp/xx.json")) {
            Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(is, Map.class);
            List<Property> properties = getProperties((Map<String, Object>)map.get("properties"));
            System.out.println(properties);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<Property> getProperties(Map<String, Object> propertiesMap) {

        List<Property> propertiesList = new ArrayList<>();

        // iterate on properties
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> propertyEntry : propertiesMap.entrySet()) {
            Property property = new Property();
            property.name = propertyEntry.getKey();
            Map<String, Object> propertyAttrsMap = (Map<String, Object>)propertyEntry.getValue();
            property.type = (String)propertyAttrsMap.get("type");
            // recursively get sub properties 
            if (propertyAttrsMap.containsKey("properties")) {
                property.subProperties = getProperties((Map<String, Object>)propertyAttrsMap.get("properties"));
            }
            propertiesList.add(property);
        }

        return propertiesList;
    }

    public static class Property {
        public String name;
        public String type;
        public List<Property> subProperties = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + " " + type + " " + subProperties;
        }
    }
}
```

using this sample input

```
{
  "description": "Something",
  "id": "abc.def.xyzjson#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "triggerTime": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Time of adjustment event",
      "source": "ab.cd",
      "pattern": "something",
      "required": true
    },
    "customerId": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Something",
      "source": "ef.gh",
      "required": true
    },
    "complex": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Something",
      "source": "ef.gh",
      "required": true,
      "properties": {
        "sub1": {
          "type": "int",
          "description": "sub1",
          "source": "ab.cd",
          "required": true
        },
        "sub2": {
          "type": "short",
          "description": "sub2",
          "source": "ab.cd",
          "required": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

produces the following output:

```
[triggerTime string [], customerId string [], complex string [sub1 int [], sub2 short []]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to your problem.

One would be what Sharon suggested with just iterating the big map.

Another solution however would be to create wrapper classes ( POJOs ) to work with, which also could provide other useful aspects depending on your scale and use case.

```
public class YourJsonObject {

private String description;

private string id;

private String object;

private JsonProperties properties;

public YourJsonObject() {

}

public JsonProperties getProperties(){
return properties;
}

public void setProperties(JsonProperties properties){
this.properties = properties;
}

public String getDescription(){
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description= description;
}

public String getId(){
return id;
}

public void setId(String id){
this.id = id;
}

//and so on with the getter setter
}


//The class JsonProperties used in YourJsonObject
public class JsonProperties{

private TriggerTime triggertime;

private Customer customerId;

public JsonProperties() {

}

public TriggerTime getTriggertime(){
return triggertime;
}

//and so on

}
```

Then somewhere else you can just do this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // create once, reuse
yourJsonObject example = new yourJsonObject(); // have your POJO you want to save
mapper.writeValue(new File("result.json"), example);
```

To read you can just use:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // create once, reuse
yourJsonObject value = mapper.readValue(new File("data.json"), yourJsonObject .class); // data.json is the json file you want to read. Else you can also pass a String into it with method overloading.
```

Both snippets are taken from my linked wiki article from jackson themselves.

Jackson should automatically be able to parse this POJO to an equivalent JSON if configured correctly. Note: Jackson has to be globally registered and has to know about it. Please read the wiki of what you use to know about it. [Jackson in 5 Minutes](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/)

Comment: so all properties have to known in advance? seems too rigid solution. also,  OP stated that properties can have sub-properties that is why recursion is needed to solve this

Comment: They have to be known in advance anyway, how else should he react to the json accordingly?
Also you can dsplay every depth of sub-properties. If you look at the POJO `JsonProperties` I defined a Pojo to automatically parse the json property `properties` with all it's properties. So the sub-property `triggertime` is included with all it's informations in the object `JsonProperties`.

Comment: they do not need to be known in advance. for my eyes, it seemed obvious. otherwise, what is the purpose of the requirement to gather all properties ?

Comment: I don't see how this solution would work if `triggertime` had `properties`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher you have to define the POJO triggertime too just like `JsonProperties`.

I admit I didn't read carefully enough that he just wants to collect the propertie names and assumed he wants to completely parse and use the json in his application. Then this would be a good solution. However with just collection some names out of it your solution is better.